# Proportional sizes of polygons QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I was wondering if I can make the polygon with the red arrow bigger than the one with the green arrow based on their difference in size in the attribute table?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That'd violate several cartographic rules. Also, a polygon is a polygon, it has a fixed area. You could, however, place a point/circle inside your polygon and vary its size based on some attribute.

Comment: yes you can. Have a look to Geometry Generator under Symbology/Layer Styling